# Java and MYSQL Syntax Issue

Tags: java, mysql, syntax

I'm trying to insert data into my MYSQL databse.  I want to insert an int into the database which I have no problem doing.  However, I want to INSERT INTO (VALUES) WHERE.  I get a MYSQL syntax error when I try this.

I can INSERT and SELECT WHERE as long as they are in two seperate statements.  Here is my code:

```
    String query = ("INSERT INTO `accounts` (inventory) " + "VALUES ('"
            + Inventory.inventory + "') WHERE username='" + Frame.username
            + "' and password = '" + Frame.password + "'");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, an `INSERT` statement can not have a `WHERE` clause. I am thinking that you want to `UPDATE` a certain record, eg

```
UPDATE accounts
SET inventory = 'valueHere'
WHERE userName = 'userHEre' AND password = 'passHere'
```

The only time an `INSERT` statement can have a `WHERE` clause is when you are inserting records from the result of a `SELECT` statement, eg

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, ..., colN)
SELECT col1, ..., colN
FROM table2
// WHERE ..your conditions here..
```

As a sidenote, your current coding style is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Consider using `PreparedStatement`.

---

Basic example of a `PreparedStatement`

```
String updateString = "UPDATE accounts SET inventory = ? WHERE userName = ? AND password = ?";
PreparedStatement updateStmt = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
updateStmt.setString(1, Inventory.inventory);
updateStmt.setString(2, Frame.username);
updateStmt.setString(3, Frame.password);
updateStmt.executeUpdate();
```

- [JDBC PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL INSERT Syntax does not support the WHERE clause so that's why you have a syntax issue. Maybe you're looking for an UPDATE :

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] tbl_name
    SET col_name1=expr1 [, col_name2=expr2 ...]
    [WHERE where_definition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not a direct answer but more of a best practice....**

You should avoid doing this type of string concatenation for any sql.  You vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and it does not scale well.  Instead you should look at using JdbcTemplates or NamedJdbcTemplate using the opensource [spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE is not applicable in INSERT INTO Syntax. You want insert a new row in the table, and you should add the username and password as well as Inventory.inventory in VALUES set.